# Перенос настроек Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Всем привет, кто знает какие файлы относятся к зависимостям и настройкам редактора, нужно безболезненно мигрировать на другой ПК?)

Comment: Такого продукта, как "Visual Studio Code 2017" в природе не существует, есть Visual Studio, а есть Visual Studio 2017. Миграция в них производится по-разному и сильно зависит от установленной конфигурации.

Answer (score 7):

Для windows:

- `.vscode` - в папке пользователя системы. Здесь установленные
  расширения.
- `'пользователь'\AppData\Roaming\Code\User` - здесь
  сохраненные настройки программы

Comment: работает ли этот вариант, если переносить с винды на linux?

Answer (score 1):

Есть расширение `Settings Sync`, которое поможет это сделать.
В расширении добавляешь свой GitHub. Далее `Shift+Alt+U` создаешь `gist`. После на другом `VSC` подключаешься к GitHub и выполняешь синхронизацию `Shift+Alt+D`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User

Linux: /home/<username>/.config/Code/User
```

Настройки содержат следующие файлы:

- settings.json - сами настройки
- keybindings.json - переопределенные пользователем сочетания клавиш